# How to order a list based on the values of tuples

Tags: python, list

Starting with some lists of tuples.

```
a = [(10,10),(20,20)]
b = [(15,15),(25,25)]
```

What list comprehension can we use to create a new list, where the items from `a, b` is in order of size?

```
c = [(10,10),(15,15),(20,20),(25,25)]
```

Comment: What's the "size"?  First element? Second element? Sum of elements?

Comment: Does it have to be a comprehension? Is there a reason you can't just use `sort`? What relative order should `(10,20)` and `(20,10)` have?

Comment: Are both of your lists already ordered???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a comprehension for this you could simply do:

```
c = a + b
c.sort()
>> [(10, 10), (15, 15), (20, 20), (25, 25)]
```

or even shorter:

```
c = sorted(a + b)
>> [(10, 10), (15, 15), (20, 20), (25, 25)]
```

Answer (score 5):

If both lists are already in sorted order...

```
c = list(heapq.merge(a, b))
```

otherwise

```
c = sorted(itertools.chain(a, b))
```

Comment: +1 for heapq. Yet I am afraid that introducing `heapq` here is like shooting a fly with a laser blaster cannon. More effective, but how to explain it to them... :)

Comment: @JakubM. This use of heapq module is rather simple though and very efficient

Comment: If the lists are already ordered, this answer *should* be accepted

Answer (score 4):

Why a list comprehension? I don't know what you mean by "size", so I'm going to guess area.

```
c = sorted(a+b, key=lambda x: x[0]*x[1])
```

Comment: @jamylak -- correct me if I'm wrong, but `operator.mul` expects *2* arguments.  using it as the key will only pass 1 argument.

Comment: This answer turns out to be what I actually needed, but limelights answered what I asked so I feel obliged to set his post as accepted answer.

Comment: @user11177 don't feel obliged to do anything. Accept the answer that solved your problem

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, you should always choose the answer that solved your problem or you thought was best!

Comment: Actually, this answer is almost your answer Limelights, only with the key being the one that the OP wants. So this answer would be the correct one to accept, since it includes the Method used by the OP and also solves the question he desired answered.

Comment: @InbarRose yeah, absolutely! As I said, he should accept the one he wants without any obligation! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain

a = [(10,10),(20,20)]
b = [(15,15),(25,25)]
sorted(chain(a, b))
# [(10, 10), (15, 15), (20, 20), (25, 25)]
```

Comment: `c = a + b` `c.sort()` will be faster than this and it's just as efficient.

Comment: @jamylak - True. But I think I would use `chain` if there were more than two lists...

Comment: good point (it would be crazy not to). Just saying for this situation though

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read the [Sorting HOWTO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/). In particular, the section on key functions might be relevant, depending on how you define "size".